# Linux hangs on boot in VMware saying: Probing EDD (edd=off to disable)

Tags: linux, vmware-server

I am having a problem booting RHEL 6 Beta in VMware Server 1.0.10
My Host OS is Windows XP Pro SP2.

When I try to boot linux, I get this on screen:

***Loading vmlinuz................................
Loading initrd.img......................................
........................................................
........................................................
........................................................
...................ready.
Probing EDD (edd=off to disable)... ok***

And it appears to hang.

I tried passing edd=off parameter to kernel by editing the kernel boot line in GRUB, but it doesn't work.

Thanks,
Anil

Answer (score 1):

Use the newer version vmware server, such 2.0 or VirtualBox/KVM/Xen.

Comment: Is this a bug with VMware Server 1.X?